# iText PdfStamper not working in Chrome 

Tags: google-chrome, itext

I have functionality where I need to print the report which I displayed in the webpage. I used PdfStamper to show a print dialog box. Here is the code used in my application:

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(reportOutputContent);
PdfStamper stamper;
try {
    stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, response.getOutputStream());
    stamper.setPageAction(PdfWriter.PAGE_OPEN, new PdfAction(PdfAction.PRINTDIALOG), 1);
    stamper.close();
} catch (PdfException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (com.itextpdf.text.DocumentException e) { 
    e.printStackTrace(); 
} 
response.flushBuffer();
return null;
```

But this is working good in IE, FF and Safari but it's failing in Chrome.

Comment: What is failing? No PDF is shown? The print dialog is not shown?